# How to tap the full power of a 3-phase circuit

Tags: power-supply, three-phase, power-engineering

I know I can power my high voltage single phase AC or DC circuit by tapping either one of the L-1 to L-3 legs and return a neutral to the neutral line however I'll only get as much power from one 60Hz cycle.

However is there a way to absorb all the current from 3 lines and convert that supply to a high power,  high voltage single phase AC or DC circuit where only a single power source is needed but with very high and stable current?

Some applications are: EV fast battery charging?

Comment: Look up *three phase bridge rectifier.*

Comment: ... which is pretty much how every vehicle alternator made in the last half century works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned from user Pat this is possible by using three phase bridge rectifier. However the diodes conduct only if phase voltage is higher than the other phase voltage and of course together higher that output capacitor or battery voltage. The result is a spiking current, not a contionous current.

[Source if the image](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/404473/82111)

[image]

You can see the waveform of a phase current, it's far from sine wave.

On the other hand, if you want a phase to have a nice sine wave you can use a PFC circuit. If the needed voltage is higher than mains voltage a boost converter is used that can be combined with PFC with the same inductor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to convert a 3-phase AC supply to a DC supply by using a full-wave 3-phase bridge rectifier. Assuming a constant DC load, each phase of the AC supply will be loaded equally.

The resulting DC supply could then be converted to a single phase AC supply using pulse width modulation. Again, given a constant downstream single phase AC load, each phase of the upstream 3-phase AC supply would be loaded equally.

Comment: "Again, given a constant downstream single phase AC load, each phase of the upstream 3-phase AC supply would be loaded equally." What about adding more capacitors on the DC side?

Comment: A practical circuit would certainly include capacitance on the DC bus to smooth the voltage output. The point I was making is that the downstream single phase load does not result in an unbalanced load for the upstream 3-phase supply (as it would if connected directly across one phase of the supply without the rectifier/inverter). As Marko points out, current does not flow continuously on each phase, as only one pair of diodes will conduct at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You would be referring to balanced loads for a three phase AC supply.

Here are some examples.

- Lamp loads
- Linear or switch-mode DC power supplies
- Battery chargers
- Welding rectifiers
- AC motors
- Variable frequency drives